Gradle error: Unsupported class file major version 63
In a Gradle project, how do I ensure that the downloaded Maven dependency libraries are compiled with the compatible Java version used in my project? I'm using Java version 17 in the project, but if a library downloaded from the Maven repository is compiled with Java 19, I encounter an "UnsupportedClassVersionError." How can I prevent this in a Gradle project?
Is there any plugin available to automatically check and fail the build with the detailed report?
Currently, I'm getting below error which is not so useful.
Execution failed for task ':sample:analyzeJarMain'.
> Unsupported class file major version 63

At least, I would like to know which dependency (or library) causing this issue.

Select a version of the library that was built for Java 17.

the dependency (or library) that is causing this, is the one that is compiled with Java 19

This question can be answered. The author is in part asking how to debug the issue.

You can learn which classes are being loaded from where, by passing in -verbose to the JVM.  An easy way is to set the JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS variable similar to export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-verbose"

What is the Gradle version? It sounds like you're using a Gradle version which doesn't support Java 19.

@MarkRotteveel Gradle 7.6.4

Hmm, that version should support Java 19. Are you sure you're executing Gradle with Java 19 or higher? You may want to add --stacktrace to your Gradle command to get the full stacktrace to see where it is triggered. That might give a hint as to where the problem is.

https://docs.gradle.org/8.8-rc-1/userguide/compatibility.html
